# Is it possible to make a Bash file run as root in crontab?

Tags: bash, cron

I need that [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) file to run periodically, and it must be as root.

Is that possible?

```
[root@file nutch-0.9]# locate crontab
/etc/crontab
/etc/sysconfig/crontab
/usr/bin/crontab
/usr/share/man/man1/crontab.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1p/crontab.1p.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/crontab.5.gz
/usr/share/vim/vim71/syntax/crontab.vim
[root@file nutch-0.9]#
```

Comment: You could also try asking this question on serverfault.

Answer (score 21):

Yes, just add it to the root users' [crontab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Overview); run the `crontab -e` command.

The places cron stores its files can be a little bizzare, so use the `crontab -e` command which will make sure it's in the right place, and I believe it checks the syntax.

Comment: I've listed all crontab files,which do you mean I should modify?

Comment: Instead of directly modifying a crontab file yourself, whatsisname is suggesting you use the "crontab -e" command, which will edit the correct crontab.

Answer (score 16):

You can just do

```
crontab -e
```

as root.

Comment: Should it be `sudo crontab -e`? @FreeMemory

Comment: @Alper You don't need `sudo` while being **root**

Answer (score 7):

Just specify `root` as the user for the entry in `/etc/crontab`:

```
0 0 *  * *  root  somecommand
```

Alternatively you can also add the command to root's personal crontab by using `crontab -e` as root.

Comment: Thank you,BTW,could you tell me what the other crontab files are for?

Comment: The crontab file in /usr/bin is the executable that opens an editor if you type "crontab -e". The files below /usr/share/man are the manual pages you get when typing "man crontab". /usr/share/vim*/sytax/crontab.vim is special syntax highlighting for vim (activated for crontab files).

Comment: This did not work for me. I got the message /bin/sh:1root: not found

Comment: this cause cron to interpret "root" as a command.

Answer (score 5):

No matter what, you will need to have access to the root user account.

1. you can add it to the root crontab, as suggested
2. you can use sudo, as suggested
3. you can use the setuid bit.  The issue with the setuid bit is that it needs to be a compiled program.  If it is compiled, you can "chmod 4755" and set the owner of the file to root, and it will run as root.  If it is not compiled, you can write a tiny wrapper in C (or any other compiled programming language) that simply calls your script, and setuid on the wrapper, and make sure the wrapper is owned by root.

My advice?  Use root crontab. It's what it's there for.

Also, there is no user entry in crontab as suggested by sth...the syntax is:

```
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59) 
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ... 
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)  OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat 
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
```

If you want to enter something in crontab as root, just login to your root account, "crontab -e" and voila...root crontab.

Comment: In some (older) versions of cron, there is a user specified in the crontab.  See http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe all of the entries in root's crontab run as root. You can just make it invoke a Bash script as the action and it should do what you want.

Answer (score -2):

One way of doing this (via sudo):

1. You need to set up sudo prilvileges for the account to run without entering in the user credentials
2. Add "sudo /path/to/command" (without the ") to run the command as root. You can also add parameters to the command.