# Do commands run with root permissions, if they're inside a bash script that's executed via a crontab under root

Tags: linux, bash, cron, root

If a crontab is created for the root user under Linux, using
`sudo crontab -e`, then anything that's directly run by the crontab will use root permissions - see [Is it possible to make a Bash file run as root in crontab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015485/is-it-possible-to-make-a-bash-file-run-as-root-in-crontab)

Does this mean that any commands *within* the bash script will also inherit root permissions, or will any commands within the bash script need to be explicitly executed with root permissions e.g. `sudo docker ps`?

Comment: Unless they explicitly drop privileges, like e.g. apache or nginx, yes.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between the root user and root permissions. All scripts in `root`'s crontab will run as `root`, and all commands therein will also run as `root`, with all associated permissions.

Comment: Thanks - is there a reference that confirms that?

Comment: POSIX and Vixie Cron take it for granted that a user's crontab runs as them, but [ISC Cron](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab) says that "Each user has their own crontab, and commands in any given crontab will be executed as the user who owns the crontab". Shells not switching users when running commands is implied by statements like POSIX "A subshell environment shall be created as a duplicate of the shell environment"